# Express JS Middleware Mongoose filter and sort query I don't get what I expect to get and it's not sorting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

This is the middleware to filter and sort. I tried to modify this middleware but it does not work how I would like it to:

```
 const aliasTopMenu = (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.sort = '-price';
  req.query.fields = 'name,price,rating';
  req.query.limit = '3';
  next();
};
```

In router file, just pass the middleware before function to get data

```
express.Route().route('/top-5-menu').get(aliasTopMenu, getAllItems);
```

`getAllItems` function: this function to get all and filter some data as user want

```
const getAllItems = AsyncWrapper(async (req, res) => {
  //1)filtring

  const queryObj = { ...req.query };
  const excludField = ['page', 'sort', 'limit', 'fields'];
  excludField.forEach((el) => {
    delete queryObj[el];
  });
  //advanced filtring
  let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
  queryStr = queryStr.replace(/(gt|gte|lte|lt)/g, (matched) => {
    return `$${matched}`;
  });
  let query = await Item.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));

  //2) sorting

  if (req.query.sort) {
    const sortBy = req.query.sort.split(',').join(' ');
    query = await Item.find(JSON.parse(queryStr)).sort(sortBy);
  }
  //3)Field limiting
  if (req.query.fields) {
    const fields = req.query.fields.split(',').join(' ');

    query = await Item.find(JSON.parse(queryStr)).select(fields);
  }
  //Pagination page and limit
  if (req.query.page) {
    const page = req.query.page * 1 || 1;
    const limit = req.query.limit * 1 || 100;
    const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
    const numItems = await Item.countDocuments();
    if (skip >= numItems) {
      throw new Error('this page do not exist');
    }
    query = await Item.find(JSON.parse(queryStr)).skip(skip).limit(limit);
  }

  //execute query

  const items = await query;

  res.status(200).json(items);
});
```

Result of this query "{{URL}}/items/top-5-menu" {{URL}} is global variable contains localhost and prot:

```
 [
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62aa6f0cb6cf327c8c4d219a",
        "name": "Pizza",
        "price": 350
    },
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62aa6f15b6cf327c8c4d219c",
        "name": "Sawarma",
        "price": 150
    },
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62acf53798c9c74218de901f",
        "name": "Burger",
        "price": 250
    },
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62acf56298c9c74218de9021",
        "name": "Pizza",
        "price": 400
    },
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62ad10569b344b2b223e6ea4",
        "name": "Shawarma",
        "price": 500
    },
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62ad10709b344b2b223e6ea6",
        "name": "takos",
        "price": 400
    },
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62ad10769b344b2b223e6ea8",
        "name": "takos",
        "price": 250
    },
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62ad10839b344b2b223e6eaa",
        "name": "chiken",
        "price": 400
    },
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62ad108f9b344b2b223e6eac",
        "name": "chiken",
        "price": 350
    },
    {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "_id": "62ad109b9b344b2b223e6eae",
        "name": "chiken",
        "price": 350
    }
]
```

It doesn't sort data by price.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was here look how await key word i used but when i tried it's working hope that's help someone who have this type of error

```
 let query = await Item.find(JSON.parse(queryStr))
query = await Item.find(JSON.parse(queryStr)).sort(sortBy);
query = await Item.find(JSON.parse(queryStr)).select(fields);
query = await Item.find(JSON.parse(queryStr)).skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

solution is like that :

```
let query = Item.find(JSON.parse(queryStr))
  query = query.sort(sortBy);
    query = query.select(fields);
    query = query.skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

than when you make all your change await

```
const items = await query;
```